# Shell Script Loop from PHP not working

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to call a shell script loop using the `shell_exec()` php function but with no avail.

I can do `shell_exec("ls")` with no problem.

I can ssh to the server and do `for f in`ls`; do echo $f ; done` with no problem.

But when I combine the two,

```
shell_exec("for f in `ls` ; do echo $f ; done")
```

I get nothing as output (nor NULL as error, I checked).

What am I missing here?

P.S: The for loop I am using here is not one I intend to use, it's just to make it clearer.

Comment: Turn on errors, and set error reporting to E_ALL - you have at least a notice here

Answer (score 4):

```
echo shell_exec("for f in `ls` ; do echo \$f ; done");
```

Your mistakes:

1. Missed `echo`
2. `$` sign should be escaped as soon as you're using double quotes (or double quotes may be replaced with single quotes instead)

Pro tip: **always** develop with `error_reporting` level `E_ALL` (or higher) and `display_errors 1`

Comment: how does it pick which shell to use?

Comment: @j_mcnally: that's actually an interesting question. I honestly don't know and haven't thought about that ever

Comment: Internally it uses (for linux) `popen`, but not sure how it picks the shell in case if current user don't have any assigned (`/bin/false`)

Comment: @j_mcnally: seems like the one that was used to run the webserver (or current user's if run by CLI)

Comment: I posted this as a question if you want to chime in. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826223/how-does-shell-exec-pick-which-shell-to-use#comment24259047_16826223

Comment: @j_mcnally: oh, I was on half way to post the similar