# How does shell_exec() pick which shell to use?

Tags: php

The question came up in another thread. Figured I would ask.

[Shell Script Loop from PHP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826026/shell-script-loop-from-php-not-working)

Comment: I assume is uses the C `system()` function, so it uses whatever that uses. Which will be OS-dependent (probably /bin/sh on Unix, cmd.exe on Windows).

Comment: @Barmar: Post this as the answer.

Comment: it uses popen() on linux atleast. Why /bin/sh?

Comment: @zerkms, i think Barmar is right, that /bin/sh comes from popen(), but thanks for leading use down the right path with popen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it uses `popen()`, that uses `/bin/sh` on Linux. The man page for `popen()` says:

> The command argument is a pointer to a null-terminated string containing a shell command line.  This command is passed to /bin/sh using the -c  flag; interpretation, if any, is performed by the shell.

`/bin/sh` is the only shell that POSIX guarantees will be available.

Comment: Oh, I've just read that man page but didn't spot the `/bin/sh` part, +1

Comment: @Barmar: "If it uses popen()" -- you could put a link to the exact place in the php sources https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h#L311