# Use php exec to launch a linux command with brace expansion

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

How can I force the php exec() to interpret the linux brace expansion?

I am encountering a strange behavior, and did not find a way to fix it the way I want.

I want to execute a linux command containing [brace expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) to select a batch of files,

**from php**

I am using php to generate a "random" number of files, and want then to execute a shell script which will make something with the files.

Here is my bash version:

> "$ echo $BASH_VERSION"
>
> 4.1.5(1)-release

To give a simple example, let's assume I create the following files:

> touch /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml

---

shell.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=$*
echo "\n\nFILES: $FILES"
for f in $FILES; do
  echo Posting file $f
done
```

---

test.php

```
<?php
$cmd = "./shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml";
echo"\n\nCOMMAND:\n".$cmd."\n\n";
var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));
```

---

The output of "php test.php" is:

```
COMMAND:
./shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml
string(66) "
FILES: /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml
Posting file /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml
"
```

---

I expect to have the same as if I run "./shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml" from linux terminal:

> $ ./shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml
>
> FILES: /tmp/file_1.xml /tmp/file_2.xml /tmp/file_3.xml /tmp/file_4.xml /tmp/file_5.xml /tmp/file_6.xml /tmp/file_7.xml /tmp/file_8.xml /tmp/file_9.xml /tmp/file_10.xml /tmp/file_11.xml /tmp/file_12.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_1.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_2.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_3.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_4.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_5.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_6.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_7.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_8.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_9.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_10.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_11.xml
>
> Posting file /tmp/file_12.xml

But I also tried with or without escapeshellcmd()
with exec($cmd) AND other functions like system() or eval()...
None of them did the job...

**I know that I could do the foreach loop in php, but I am sure there is a way to have this command interpreted as if it was launched from command line.**

Comment: Could you try doing it like `shell_exec("sh -c './shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml'")`

Comment: you were almost right...I needed to write /bin/bash instead of sh (no symlink from sh to bash by default) as proposed by Michael Jaros...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As [@Josh Trii Johnston has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764970/4024473), the 'outer' shell you are implicitly using to call your shell script using `shell_exec()` is probably not Bash in your case. This way, brace expansion never takes place because there is no shell capable of expanding the expression before calling your program (as it would be in an interactive Bash session).

  You could

  - try to change the shell invoked by PHP's `shell_exec()`, but this [may not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826223/how-does-shell-exec-pick-which-shell-to-use)
  - call `/bin/bash` with your program and the brace expression instead of only the brace expression: `$cmd = "/bin/bash -c './shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml'";`
  - use `eval` on the argument inside your script to expand the brace expression.
- From the `bash(1)` man page:

  > If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well. [...] When invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are read.

  Try changing

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ```

  to

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  if you expect Bash behavior (there is no brace expansion in POSIX).
- If all of the above does not help, you should make sure that brace expansion is activated by executing `set -o` (while calling your program from the PHP script). If it is off, you can turn it on using:

  ```
  set -o braceexpand
  ```

Comment: +1 (if I could - not enough reputation atm) Thanks Michael! Adding /bin/bash -c '$cmd' worked for me. (change the #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash not)   --- :)

Comment: @Bast great to hear that. Yes, if your program runs in Bash or not is actually irrelevant here because the brace expansion takes place in the shell calling it, not the shell executing it. Unless you choose the `eval` method for step 1. That would require to do step 2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used your exact example on my OS X machine and it works as expected. What user are you executing php as? Is that user's shell (`/bin/sh`) set to a non-bash shell?

```
$ php test.php

COMMAND:
./shell.sh /tmp/file_{1..12}.xml

string(555) "\n\nFILES: /tmp/file_1.xml /tmp/file_2.xml /tmp/file_3.xml /tmp/file_4.xml /tmp/file_5.xml /tmp/file_6.xml /tmp/file_7.xml /tmp/file_8.xml /tmp/file_9.xml /tmp/file_10.xml /tmp/file_11.xml /tmp/file_12.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_1.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_2.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_3.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_4.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_5.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_6.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_7.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_8.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_9.xml\nPosting file /tmp/file_10.xml\nPost"...
```