# How i can run function exec in PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec

I can't add * to my code to find file

this code work

`exec("mediaconvert -t wav -i /home/20220228/11/23401.rec -o /var/www/html/test.mp3");`

if i add a the *, it don't work

`exec("mediaconvert -t wav -i /home/20220228/11/*01.rec -o /var/www/html/test.mp3");`

p.s. in path is only one file, when i try execute this code from shell it work. Pls help me)

Comment: Try a simple `exec` with filename expansion, like `exec('ls *.php', $out); var_dump($out);` and see if `*` works as expected. Also, add the `$output` argument to your call so you actually know what your call returns. Also, **please clarify "it doesn't work**, what are the results you are getting? Are you sure your issue isn't simply with the fact that, while you're piping in multiple files,  you're defining a single output file, as in `-o /var/www/html/test.mp3`?

Answer (score 1):

Filename expansion and other [bash-specific features](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) may/will not work in other shells (e.g. standard POSIX). If your command with `*` is not executed in bash/compatible, it won't work as expected. You need to verify the environment/shell that your PHP installation executes commands in.

Run the following test script:

```
<?php
exec('echo "$SHELL"', $out); 
var_dump($out);
```

When I run the PHP script directly on CLI, I get `"/bin/bash"` for the shell that's called. When I run it via browser, curiously I get `"/sbin/nologin"` instead. There are different environments for user `apache` that executes PHP via browser calls, and the "actual" user logging in via SSH. Bash shell is not available for the Apache user by default.

These results are from a Centos7 server with Apache 2.4/PHP 8.1.4 running. Your mileage may vary. *Bottom line:* if the command you are executing depends on bash-specific features, it must execute in a bash environment, or another shell that supports the required features.

If bash is not available, your other option is using e.g. [`glob`](https://www.php.net/glob) to get files matching the pattern in your directory, and then loop over them while executing the command for each specific file.

---

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Sammitch (see comments), `/sbin/nologin`  is a common "shell name" choice for non-login users, and most likely uses `/bin/sh`. This should still allow for filename expansion/globbing. Testing browser script call with `exec('ls *.php', $out);` the wildcard functions as expected.

---

*You may find this question/answer relevant: [Use php exec to launch a linux command with brace expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762773/use-php-exec-to-launch-a-linux-command-with-brace-expansion).*

Comment: `$SHELL` is simply the the shell defined for the user in `/etc/passwd` and for non-login users like whatever runs your webserver, something like `/sbin/nologin` is a usual choice. If you were running an _interactive_ session, then that is what is used to start your login shell. That said, I'm reasonably certain that PHP's `shell_exec()` always hits `/bin/sh` which won't necessarily have all the features of bash, but will still do the globbing.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch, I have tested simple globbing and indeed it works via browser calls too (in my setup anyway). I've updated the answer to reflect your notes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do the opposite. First, get the files you want to input then you exec. For instance:

```
$input_files = ...
exec("mediaconvert -t wav -i " . $input_files . " -o /var/www/html/test.mp3");
```

Comment: problem is that i can't know full name of file, only last 2 numbers and i wanna use *

```$input_files = "/home/20220228/11/*01.rec";
exec("mediaconvert -t wav -i " . $input_files . " -o /var/www/html/test.mp3");```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find files with [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function and after that you can use exec(). You can try a similiar solution with the following code:

```
$input_files = '/home/20220228/11/*01.rec';
foreach (glob($input_files) as $filename) {
    exec("mediaconvert -t wav -i " . $filename . " -o /var/www/html/test.mp3");
}
```